# Java Running Remote Bashscript

Tags: java, remote-access

I want to connect a remote machine(has a Linux operation system) from my Java Program and I want to run a script on it. I will process the result of that script(it writes something to console) too.

What do you suggest for me? If anything needed I can explain more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run shell script on remote machine from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542626/how-to-run-shell-script-on-remote-machine-from-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are SSH libraries in java. you can use them to execute scripts on a remote machine.